# Mathematica 12.0 Dsolve solving 2D diffusion PDE

Tags: differential-equations

my friends,i meet some problems,please help me!

this is my equation and ic ,bc
[image]
[image]

[image]
this is my code .I let some constants R,in,D,F become 1，h become 2，it is convenient to calculate

```
heqn = D[u[x, y, t], {t}] == 
  D[u[x, y, t], {x, 2}] + D[u[x, y, t], {x}]/x + D[u[x, y, t], {y, 2}]

ic = u[x, y, 0] == 0

bc = {Derivative[0, 1, 0][u][x, 1, t] == 0, 
  Derivative[0, 1, 0][u][x, -1, t] == -1, 
  Derivative[1, 0, 0][u][1, y, t] == 1}


 sol = DSolveValue[{heqn, bc, ic}, u[x, y, t], {x, y, t}]
```

but the result is [image]

this is the analytical solution [image]

Answer (score 4):

What you have is 3D, not 2D. You are solving diffusion on cylindrical coordinates with symmetry (independent of $\theta$)

I borrowed an image from a web site which has lots of Mathematica pde solutions

[image]

First problem I noticed is that all your BC are Neumann. This typically results in non-unique solution up to a constant. One of the BC should be Dirichlet, else `DSolve` will not solve it.

Also, for some reason, when IC is zero, `DSolve` will not solve it. So setting IC to some constant, (then later on, you can zero out this constant in the solution works).

Another difficulty, is that you have `z` go from `-h/2` to `h/2`. This makes it harder for `DSolve`. But this is easy to workaround. Just solve from `0` to `h`. You can always rescale. It does not affect the nature of the solution.

Also, `DSolve` could not solve it, if the RHS of the Neumann was not zero (i.e. fully insulated). This might be limitation of `DSolve`. For example, changing `(D[u[r, z, t], z] /. z -> 0) == 0` to `(D[u[r, z, t], z] /. z -> 0) == -i/F` now it can not solve the PDE.

In the following, I made the BC be zero on the outside edge of the cylindrical, and kept Neumann on the bottom and top sides. Now `DSolve` can solve it.

Given all that, here is the solution

```
ClearAll["Global`*"];
lap = Laplacian[u[r, z, t], {r, theta, z}, "Cylindrical"]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
bc = {u[R, z, t] == 0, 
      (D[u[r, z, t], z] /. z -> 0) == 0, 
      (D[u[r, z, t], z] /. z -> h) == 0}

ic = u[r, z, 0] == f[r, z]; (*0 will not give solution!*)

sol = DSolve[{D[u[r, z, t], t] == lap, bc, ic}, u[r, z, t], {r, z, t}]
```

[image]

**Version 12.3.1 on windows.**